# htaccess: force www to non www adds extra slash at the end

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, gunicorn, supervisord

I'd like to force www to none www, but the rewrite seems to add another (so double) slash at the end. The setup below is for a Django/Gunicorn/Supervisor environment.

Where/why is the extra slash added? I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Old situation:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:9001/$1 [L,P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9001/
```

Current situation:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:9001/$1 [L,P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9001/
```

Comment: The redirect doesn't add a slash. I tried just the redirect in my test environment and it redirects properly to just the `domain.com/...` URL.

Comment: That's weird. Whatever I do there's this extra slash.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located? Is it located in the same directory as the index file or outside of that directory?